# How do I delimit a string into all possible character groupings of size 1 to 4

Tags: vb.net, string

i would like to take any input string and delimit it into groups. each group may be at least one character and no more than 4 characters. How do I loop to create all possible combinations?

Example:

in-string:
xoox

output:
x|o|o|x, x|oo|x, x|oox, xo|o|x, xo|ox, xoo|x, xoox

I'm writing an asp .net app using VB, but I really just need the concept for the recursion. So, an example in any language that doesn't use a special method to accomplish this would help me.

Comment: are you missing a combination? `x|o|ox`?  That would give you `2^(n-1)` combinations.

Comment: please don't repeat tags like "VB.NET" in the title. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @John: understood. I thought i had seen another post like that and i was trying to follow suit. I think I got it now.

Comment: @Ben: I likely am missing one. But, the answer below from huntaub helped me find my solution. it guarantees i won't miss any in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this...

```
Sub writeDelimination(ByVal toSplit As String, ByVal start As String)
    Dim top As Integer = 4
    If toSplit.Length < 4 Then
        top = toSplit.Length
    End If
    For i As Integer = 1 To top Step 1
        Dim split As String = toSplit.Substring(0, i)
        writeDelimination(toSplit.Substring(i, toSplit.Length - i), start + "|" + split)
    Next
    If top = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine(start)
    End If
End Sub
```

You would do the first call to the sub as `writeDelimination("xoox", Nothing)`

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, your visual representation using `|` characters to represent combined positions in the array gives a clue to how to approach this problem.

You have `2^(n-1)` possible combinations where `n` is the length of the text.  You can represent all the possible split positions using a list of binary numbers of length `n`:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

You should be able to loop through this list of binary integers and, treating `0`s for a position as false and `1`s for a position as true, determine which combinations should be joined together.  After you finish this loop, you'll have all possible combinations of the text.

Granted, there's still a good bit of VB.NET work to be done in order to generate the list of binary numbers, create output lists, etc, but hopefully this can get you started.

Comment: This is _almost_ right. You have to make sure that the binary numbers do not group more than 4 numbers together. For example, when you put in a string of length 5, you would get 1111 at the bottom of your binary list which is against the rules as the group's length is greater then 4.